# Can Dreamweaver CS5.5 really turn my web page into an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cordova, dreamweaver, smartphone

I have a fairly simple website where users can fill out a form describing a flowering plant.  They click on buttons and checkboxes to describe the leaves and flowers, and then the site returns a list of the possible plant families they are seeing.  The site is built with jQuery and all of the data are in a javascript as a series of comma-separated numbers.

The problem, of course, is that the plant ID tool is on the web and it would be much more useful if it could be a stand-alone tool on a smartphone so it would work in a remote jungle somewhere.

I've been scared off of developing an app up til now because I've heard that it costs tens of thousands of dollars.  But I keep reading that the new version of Dreamweaver can do the job for me.  Can someone clue me in on this?  Can I really build an iPhone app in Dreamweaver CS5.5 without knowing Objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  According to this link you can package a native iOS app with CS5.5:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSeffff8bffc80208478c8d43312e240fe0ad-8000.html

NOTE: You'll still need to register as an Apple iOS developer to upload apps to the app store.

You can also look into non-Objective-C tools like Corona SDK.

http://www.anscamobile.com/

Answer (score 0):

To register as an iPhone developer you do not need tens of thousands of dollars, more like 100 dollars. Writing iPhone apps is not simple, and for someone to write an app for you might cost as much. BUT, since you have your website up-and running, i would recommend adjusting the website to smartphone screen sizes, and creating an iPhone app that is basically just a wrapper to a web-browser which will show your site pages. Basically that's what CS5.5 does for you as stated. Similar platforms are Corona (as stated), phoneGap, or titanium - all of which allow creating/using web pages that show inside a native app. The app is just a shell for the webpages. Please note that titanium and phoneGap claim to be able to publish from a single project BOTH iPhone AND android native apps.

Comment: Hmm... I'm having trouble squaring your answer with other information on web pages like the one Daniel posted.  As I said in my question, the crucial thing is that the app needs to work in places where there is no phone service and no internet access.  A native app will work like that.  A web app won't.  And there are a lot of sources on the internet saying that CS5.5 will turn a web site into a native app.  Amazing if true.

Comment: Sorry for the misexplenation, but both phoneGap and titanium hold the webpages in the local filesystem, so you have a native app, running a small browser window, running your pages on the local machine, no internet required. CS5.5 apparently does the same.